# How to remove network connections manually that aren't displayed in Edit Connections dialog?

Tags: networking, network-manager, connection, modem

I have collected several network connections over time. When I go to `Network` menu in topbar, and to `Edit`, the `Network Connections` dialog shows just one out of three connections. The other two are not modem connections. One is mobile connection and another a tablet connection. Here are the screenshots:

The `Network` menu:

[image: The Network menu]

---

The `Network Connections` dialog box:

[image: The Network Connections dialog]

The connections I want to remove are: "2690 Network" (a Nokia 2690 was once connected for internet) and the "Abhimanyu Network" (when I connected my tablet for internet).

**None of these are VPN connections.**

If these cannot be removed I want to know whether there's a file that includes data on the connections which I can manipulate to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Can you provide images of this? I would expect all of the known connections to show up when  you choose "edit". At least that is my experience from using VPNs for a long time.

Comment: Install "shutter". It allows you to make screenshots of cascading menus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The network connections used by `Network Manager` are stored in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`. Each connection has its own file with the connection name as its name.

Open a terminal and delete the file associated with your connection with the `rm` command.

For example,

`root@usermachine:/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections# rm filename`

**Note:** You need root privileges to do this.